# Python - take rows of data and place into single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with numerous rows. I would like to take the multiple columns and condense it to one column.

```
Player         |    0             |     1     |     2     | 3         |  4
Edgerrin James | 1st Tm All-Conf. | AP 1st Tm | FW 1st Tm | SN 1st Tm | Pro Bowl
Tony Gonzalez  | 1st Tm All-Conf. | AP 1st Tm | None      | None      | None
...            |  ...             | ...       | ...       | ...       | ...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to restructure it so the awards are all in one column. So it would look like a dataframe as follows:

```
Player         | awardID
Edgerrin James | 1st Tm All-Conf.
Edgerrin James | AP 1st Tm
Edgerrin James | FW 1st Tm 
Edgerrin James | SN 1st Tm
Edgerrin James | Pro Bowl
Tony Gonzalez  | 1st Tm All-Conf.
Tony Gonzalez  | AP 1st Tm
```

If the 'None' cells are also included, I'd be fine with that because I know how to filter those out after, but can't figure out the first part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set_index` on `Player` and `stack`

```
In [750]: df.set_index('Player').stack().reset_index(name='awardID').drop('level_1', 1)
Out[750]:
           Player           awardID
0  Edgerrin James  1st Tm All-Conf.
1  Edgerrin James         AP 1st Tm
2  Edgerrin James         FW 1st Tm
3  Edgerrin James         SN 1st Tm
4  Edgerrin James          Pro Bowl
5   Tony Gonzalez  1st Tm All-Conf.
6   Tony Gonzalez         AP 1st Tm
7   Tony Gonzalez              None
8   Tony Gonzalez              None
9   Tony Gonzalez              None
```

Optinally, remove `None` using `query`

```
In [757]: (df.set_index('Player')
             .stack()
             .reset_index(name='awardID')
             .drop('level_1', 1)
             .query('awardID != "None"'))
Out[757]:
           Player           awardID
0  Edgerrin James  1st Tm All-Conf.
1  Edgerrin James         AP 1st Tm
2  Edgerrin James         FW 1st Tm
3  Edgerrin James         SN 1st Tm
4  Edgerrin James          Pro Bowl
5   Tony Gonzalez  1st Tm All-Conf.
6   Tony Gonzalez         AP 1st Tm
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I meant to include what I was thinking and trying. which was:

df.set_index('Player', inplace=True)
df = test.stack().reset_index(drop=False)
df.drop('level_1', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={0: 'awardID'}, inplace=True)
df = test.loc[test['awardID'] != 'None']

just didn't know of a concise way. So it looks like I had the right idea, just needed to clean it up

Answer (score 1):

solution without panda
first save any row in a string like `s`

```
  def mylist(string):

   string = string.split('|')
   length = len(string)-1
   for i in range(length):
    print string[0],string[i+1:i+2],'\n'

  s1 = 'Edgerrin James | 1st Tm All-Conf. | AP 1st Tm | FW 1st Tm | SN 1st Tm | Pro Bowl'

  s2 = 'Tony Gonzalez  | 1st Tm All-Conf. | AP 1st Tm | None      | None      | None'


 mylist(s1)
 mylist(s2)
```

ouput:

```
Edgerrin James  [' 1st Tm All-Conf. '] 

Edgerrin James  [' AP 1st Tm '] 

Edgerrin James  [' FW 1st Tm '] 

Edgerrin James  [' SN 1st Tm '] 

Tony Gonzalez   [' 1st Tm All-Conf. '] 

Tony Gonzalez   [' AP 1st Tm '] 

Tony Gonzalez   [' None      '] 

Tony Gonzalez   [' None      '] 

Tony Gonzalez   [' None']
```

do this for all player and rows